# Optimal container to simulate a pile of card

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, optimization, stl

I'm implementing a game and I'm looking for a suitable container to simulate a pile of cards.

Mandatory conditions:

1. Container can be randomly shuffled (`random iterators` needed, `std::list` excluded)
2. Container can be sorted
3. First element can be popped out (draw a card from top)
4. Elements can be inserted at the end (discard cards to bottom)

So far, I'm using a `std::vector<District>` where `District` is an `enum class` representing a card value.

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/hgZKo1)

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

namespace Citadel
{
    enum class District
    {
        UNINITIALIZED,
        FORTRESS,
        MANOR,
        // etc
    };

    class DistrictDeck
    {
    public:
        void Setup(const std::vector<District>& availableDistricts)
        {
            // Simplified filling...
            for (const auto district : availableDistricts)
            {
                pileOfCards_.push_back(district);
            }

            // Once all cards have been pushed, shuffle them
            std::random_shuffle(std::begin(pileOfCards_), std::end(pileOfCards_));
        }

        // Pick a district card from top of the stack
        District Draw()
        {
            District district = District::UNINITIALIZED;

            if (pileOfCards_.size() > 0)
            {
                district = pileOfCards_.front();
                pileOfCards_.erase(std::begin(pileOfCards_));
            }

            return district;
        }

        // Put a district card below the bottom of the stack
        void Discard(const District district)
        {
            pileOfCards_.push_back(district);
        }

    private:
        std::vector<District> pileOfCards_;
    };
}

int main()
{
}
```

Which container could replace `std::vector` in my precise case ?

Comment: A `std::vector` is fine, but you may also want to take a look at `std::deque`.

Comment: Since cards are small things, I'd just use a fixed-size array. C++ programmers still remember how to use "primitive" arrays, don't they?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker, some `DistrictDeck` instances can have more or less cards, I prefer to stick to dynamic container. I know I could template class to build a tailored array but I like keeping maintenance effort low.

Comment: Use a `vector` as a circular buffer, i.e. keep a starting and an end index. It is better than a `deque` because in your case the maximum number of cards is bounded,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, keeping vectors could be a good alternative.

If you have to remove very often elements at the begin of the pile of cards and want to avoid lots of move that would be required by a vector,  you could however opt for **[`deque`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/)**:

```
deque<int> q; 
default_random_engine rndgen;
q.push_front(11);
q.push_back(12);                     // requirement 4
q.push_front(15);
q.push_front(20); 
cout << q.front() <<endl;            // requirement 3
q.pop_front();                       //    "   "
cout << q.at(2)<<endl;               // + random access
sort(q.begin(), q.end());            // requirement 2
shuffle(q.begin(), q.end(), rndgen); // requirement 1
```

[live demo](https://ideone.com/6O8JmI)

Worth to mention:  deque have random iterators, perform insertion/access at begin or end of the queue in constant time,  and while insertion might invalidate iterators, the pointer and references to elements remain valid.

Answer (score 2):

Vector would work fine for your purposes. Shuffling can be performed optimally (O(n)) using a [Fisher Yates Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

I should additionally note that based on the complexity in std::random_shuffle, this already looks to be what you're using.

Answer (score 0):

How about keeping vector? That seems to be a reasonable choice - how many cards do you expect to keep in there? A contiguous store is often preferable since that avoids most memory access performance problems.

You can also use an std::array or just a plain array if you know the maximum number of cards you are going to use.

As always, measure your performance to see that you actually have a performance problem.

Comment: My main concern about std::vector is about drawing card `pileOfCards_.erase(std::begin(pileOfCards_));` thus shifting memory but I guess for `enum class`, it's not a big deal.

Comment: For small amounts of cards, copying these enums is going to be fast. I'm guessing that you are not going to be doing this operation that many times per millisecond either...

Comment: That's right, I was just curious about a way of doing this better.